# show() function doesn't seem to work as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, user-interface

I am trying to create a webpage with a menu on the left side and a content area on the right side. Mockup image below to give you an idea:

[image]

I am using jQuery UI to try to accomplish this. The goal is to have the content area on the right side to be set based on the menu item selected on the left. The area will always be a tabbed layout, but the content and amount of tabs will be different for each of the item selected from the left menu. Eventually, I want to integrate this into an ASP.NET MVC 5 app to include user authorization and roles affecting what menu items and tabs will be visible based on the logged in user. But for now, I am simply trying to get the tab menu to show up based on what I click on the left menu, and to show it specifically upon clicking one specific item. For the others, it will hide it again (I have not tried to implement the re-hiding yet, and that is not part of this question; I just want to get the initial show() to work).

So right now my approach is to hide the tabs on page ready, then use a function to display it when clicked, using the jQuery show() function. However, this doesn't work (tried in firefox and IE).

My attempt is at: https://jsfiddle.net/3mo28z1t/5/

In the fiddle, in the javascript section, if you change the "hide" to "show"

```
$("#tabsuseradmin").hide();
```

you will see the tabs menu, in case you want to get an idea of the layout before trying to fix the issue.

Specifically, I want the action of clicking on "Left menu item 3" to show the tabs.

Thank you.

Comment: `hide()` and `show()` are jQuery methods. You need to call them on a jQuery object, not a DOMElement - hence the error in the console. Also, please note for future questions that you should include the code in the question, just in case the third party site with your demo goes down

Comment: I will remember that for the future. Thank you all for the responses, they are all helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cleaned your fiddle up so that your scripts/css were in external resources. You must first define the target and then call the function with the target - you haven't targeted the individual tabs(i haven't done this for you either, i'm just pointing it out) Also you can't use show as a function name, as its reserved.

What i did do is create a `toggle` on the #leftmenu>li  - see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/2rokcffw/)

```js
$(function() {
   $("#tabsuseradmin").tabs();
   $("#leftmenu").menu();
 });

$('#leftmenu>li').on('click', function(){
  $("#tabsuseradmin").toggle();
});

 $(function showTab(target) {
   document.getElementById(target).show();
 });
 
 $(function hideTab(target) {
   document.getElementById(target).hide();
 });
```

```css
#leftmenu {
  display: inline-block;
}

#tabsuseradmin {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<body>

    <ul id="leftmenu">
      <li>Left menu item 1</li>
      <li>Left menu item 2</li>
      <li>Left menu item 3</li>
      <li>Left menu item 4</li>
    </ul>

    <div id="tabsuseradmin">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab first</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab second</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Tab third</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div id="tabs-1">
        <p>Tab 1</p>
      </div>
      <div id="tabs-2">
        <p>Tab 2</p>
      </div>
      <div id="tabs-3">
        <p>Tab 3</p>
      </div>
    </div>


  </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example you are using `document.getElementById(target).show();`, but `.show` is a jQuery method

you should use something like :

- `$(document.getElementById(target)).show();`
- `$('#'+target).show();`

You can also declare your event handler differently to avoid the problem seen in jsfiddle (that show is not defined), see [my updated jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3mo28z1t/10/) for that

Answer (score 1):

```
<li id="clicker" onclick="show('tabsuseradmin')">Left menu item 3</li>


$(document).ready(
    function(){
        $("#clicker").click(function () {
            $("#tabsuseradmin").show();
        });

    });
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3mo28z1t/9/)

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in your code. If you check console, it specifically says - show is not defined. Show & hide are methods provided by jQuery. They are not the same in javascript.